Gamma function at negative integers and neutrix calculus
From what I learnt earlier, $\Gamma(-j)$ is not defined for $j=1,2,\ldots$. However,from "Some Results on the Gamma Function for Negative Integers" I get that  $\Gamma(-j)$ is defined using neutrix calculus.
I had never heard of this before a few days ago, but I am wondering what this means. Can I still get values for $\Gamma(-j)$ for $j=1,2,\ldots$ and what does neutrix calculus mean?
In particular, what I wonder is that if there is an expression involving the  $\Gamma(\cdot)$ function at negative integers, and I know that the expression exists, then can use this approach be used to evaluate the expression?

I have never heard of neutrix calculus. It seems to be some sort of regularization technique. Which is to say, the values it produces are not values in the usual mathematical sense, but some sort of extension that (in my opinion) is more likely to cause confusion than to have any usefulness.

Indeed, I wonder if the meaning of all this is that you can use it to evaluate expressions that involve $\Gamma(\cdot)$ at integers but are known to exist. I have edited my question with this clarification.

I will say that the addition of the last paragraph definitely improves the post by asking a more concrete question. (I'm skeptical that the answer is yes, but that's a different issue.)

The conventional view: $\Gamma(z)$ has poles at $z=0-1,-2,-3,\cdots$.
It has Laurent series expansions there.  For example, at $z=0$:
$$
\Gamma(z) = \frac{1}{z}-\gamma+ \left( {\frac {{\pi}^{2}}{12}}+{\frac {{\gamma}^{2}
}{2}} \right) z+ \left( -{\frac {\zeta \left( 3 \right) }{3}}-{\frac {
{\pi}^{2}\gamma}{12}}-{\frac {{\gamma}^{3}}{6}} \right) {z}^{2}+O
 \left( {z}^{3} \right) 
$$
as $z \to 0$.

And, using surreal numbers, one can write expressions for germs from the left and right of the poles (of course, they would be of different sign).

Wow, I had never  previosly heard of surreal numbers. But my question still stands. Can I use this specification to calculate something that I know exists, but involves the $\Gamma(\cdot)$ function at negative integers? Thanks!
